# .net 4 mvc2 output caching substitute name

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-2, caching

I have output caching implemented at controller level

```
[OutputCache(CacheProfile = "MyProfile")]
public Result MyControllerAction()....
```

I have some text in matching view (Views/MyController/MyControllerAction.aspx) that needs to change with each page load, even though the returned page is cached. I think this is also called donut caching.

How can I accomplish this? And where do I need to put the callback function if indeed this is possible. Can I specify the callback on Controller level or Page level.

Thanks

--MB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.Net MVC does not yet support donut caching; it's planned for version 3.